# HtmlHelper to create a unordered list with max of 2 list elements

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to make an HtmlHelper method to generate the Html for an unordered list with two li tags in it. The value coming in would be an IEnumerable of two objects, with each I want a string from each object to be visible in the li tag.

```
   <div id="pages">
    <ul>
        <li>somePage1.jpg</li>  <--One of the two objects in the enumerable
        <li>somePage.jpg</li>   <--Second of the two objects in the enumerable
    </ul>
  </div>
```

for each model object passed in, the previous code will be generated.

Thanks in advance. I hope I described my situation well enough. This is my first time using this technique.

Comment: Nobody is going to write it for you. Make an attempt at it and research it and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Im not asking for someone to write it, I am asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, something like this (quick and dirty adaption from one of my helpers but not tested for your case). I suggest you do some research - there are plenty of examples on web.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TaskTableFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
  Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
  // Get the model metadata
  ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata
    .FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
  IEnumerable<string> items= metaData.Model as IEnumerable<string>;
  if (items == null || items.Count() != 2)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid collection");
  }
  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
  TagBuilder first = new TagBuilder("li");
  first.InnerHtml = items.First();
  html.Append(first.ToString());
  TagBuilder second = new TagBuilder("li");
  second.InnerHtml = items.Last();
  html.Append(second.ToString());
  TagBuilder list = new TagBuilder("ul");
  list.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(list.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.